# How To Make an Ajax Request inside a Azure Mobile Services api

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I want to make a jquery ajax post inside my azure mobile services api get method. that is, something like I have below.  That is, I want the GET method to return data that returns something from ithe result of my ajax POST.

It's not obvious how I would do that.

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(x) { return MYLIST },
  dataType: dataType
});

   response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Hello World!' });
};
```

UPDATE:

Per Carlos Post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/12/expanded-login-scopes-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx I now understand that the exports.get code should be in the API section of the azure mobile service.  When I put that code into that section I get an Internal Error, 500 in my failure event of the jquery call.  my alert does show I successfully logged into google.

```
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://svcc.azure-mobile.net/', val);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit1").click(function () {
            client.login("google").done(function (results) {
                alert("You are now logged in as google: " + results.userId);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://xxxxx.azure-mobile.net/api/test1",
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        debugger;
                        //data - response from server
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some node.js module which allows you to make HTTP requests. The simplest one is the ['request' module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request), which you can `require` on a server script and use it to make requests. For example, this code should do what you want:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var req = require('request');
    req({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ theBody: [ 'hello', 'world' ]}),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }, function(err, result) {
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: to get other data from odata services like google, would this be the way to go? Is there a way to access google key/secret data that is in the azure identity section in scripts?

Comment: HI Carlos, ignore my above comment. Now I understand you December post much better. I updated my sample above to include calling the get method from your example and I'm now getting a 500, internal error.

Comment: and one more hint, identities is null is the error coming from my test1 api call.  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9cy44nb6topzrxp/az1.png

Comment: I found another Carlos article saying that I had to enable this as a preview feature. I did that and I still get nothing back from getIdentities.  see this for how I enabled.  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4amjcr1hpvebn2y/az2.png

Comment: updated picture from comment above with enabling preview feature users https://dl.dropbox.com/s/muohffefpnyfkz9/az3.png